# Unknown validator: 'AbsenceValidator' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

please help me to fix the problem
I added :check attribute to my Person model. Then I added validation. Here it is:

```
validates :check, :absence => true
```

And after that it stopped working and I got this:

```
Unknown validator: 'AbsenceValidator' (ArgumentError)
```

According to this article it should work
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#absence

But it doesn't.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.12

Comment: You are reading the guides version related to Rails 4.0; there is no absence validator on Rails 3.2. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17) are the docs of Rails 3.2, and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17) the guides

Comment: ooops. Thank you!
then I would update my question:
are there any workarounds to achieve the same purpose — to get an attribute which is always blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in Rails 3.

```
validate :check_is_absent

def check_is_absent
  errors.add(:check, "check is present") if check.present?
end
```

`presence` validator helper uses `blank?` to determine attribute's presence and `absence` helper uses `present?` to determine attribute's absence.

Answer (score 1):

`validates_absence_of :column_name, absence: true`/`validates_absence_of :column_name` on Rails 3.2 are just... absent.

Instead, you can use a [custom validation block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate):

```
validate(:check) { errors.add(:check, :absence) if check.present? }
```

Bonus: you can configure your locale (f.e. `config/locales/en.yml`) in order to get the same message for the `:absence` errors:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        absence: "must be blank"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!


Yet in fact I don't need a locale configuration as this parameter is designed to protect my form from spam. So if the field (i.e. column) is fulfilled, so it's a spamer)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still cares. Some time ago I created this for rails 3.2:

https://github.com/robotex82/rails_tools-absence_validator

Or add it to your gemfile like this:

```
gem install rails_tools-absence_validator
```

And use it like in rails 4.